# Proof of theorem of singular homology of spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am studying the proof of Singular homology of spheres from notes here( Page 9 and 10 specifically):[http://math.columbia.edu/~syu/s19-eat/s19-eat-notes-mar28.pdf](http://math.columbia.edu/%7Esyu/s19-eat/s19-eat-notes-mar28.pdf) . Actually, this proof was covered in my topology class but I was ill and hence I couldn't understand the proof written in notes. So, I thought of looking a proof on internet and I couldn't understand that as well.

But unfortunately, I am not able to understand much of the proof. I have tried very hard to make sense of it. So, I am posting question based on it here, hoping some one will reply:

(1) How does in the 5th line of the proof $H_n(A) \oplus H_n(B) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} $ if n=0 and 0 elsewhere? how exactly to use that $A,B$ are contractible to a point to deduce what is written?

(2)How does it implies that for $i\geq 1$ , we get $0 \to H_{i+1} (\mathbb{S}^n) \to H_i(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}) \to 0$ is exact?

(3) I understand how author deduced that $H_{i+1} (\mathbb{S}^n) \cong H_i (\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$ but how does induction implies that  $H_i(\mathbb{S}^n) \cong H_1 (\mathbb{S}^{n+1-i})$?

(4) If n>1 , then how does author writes that $H_0(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}) = H_0( \mathbb{S}^n)=0$ and how does it implies that $H_1(\mathbb{S}^n)=0$.

(5) If n=1, then how can I get that $0 \to H_1(\mathbb{S}^{1}) \to \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$ is exact, I think I will get $0 \to H_1(\mathbb{S}^{1}) \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$ is exact and how does we get $H_1 (\mathbb{S}^0)=0$.

I am very sorry that I have so many questions. I am sorry but I really want to understand the proof. I shall be really thankful for any one who even answers 1 part of it.

Thanks!

Comment: For (3) you have a typo: please compare what you wrote to the text. (Your second subscript $i$ should $1$ instead.)

Comment: For (5), the computation of the homology of $S^0$ depends on the observation that $S^0$ is the disjoint union of two points, and you should be able to compute (a) the homology of a single point and also (b) the homology of a disjoint union of two spaces in terms of the homology of each individual piece.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ya, I revised my notes again today and now (1) is clear to me.

Comment: @3ibfwcbi $H_1(\mathbb S^1)$ is not zero.

Comment: For item (4), $H_0(S^n)$ is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

> (1) How does in the 5th line of the proof $H_n(A) \oplus H_n(B) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} $ if n=0 and 0 elsewhere? how exactly to use that $A,B$ are contractible to a point to deduce what is written?

What you need to learn is that if $X$ is contractible space then

$$H_i(X)=\begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z} &\text{if }i=0 \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

This follows from the fact that $H_i$ is homotopy invariant, and thus $H_i(X)\simeq H_i(\{*\})$ with singleton on the right. And homology for a singleton can be very easily calculated manually, directly from the definition.

> (2) How does it implies that for $i\geq 1$ , we get $0 \to H_{i+1} (\mathbb{S}^n) \to H_i(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}) \to 0$ is exact?

This is Meyer-Vietoris. The author just put $0$ where the homology vanishes and replaced $A\cap B$ with $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ (there's a minor mistake in the paper - the author writes $A\cap B=\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, but there is no equality here, not even homeomorphism, but homotopy equivalence only).

> (3) I understand how author deduced that $H_{i+1} (\mathbb{S}^n) \cong H_i (\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$ but how does induction implies that  $H_i(\mathbb{S}^n) \cong H_1 (\mathbb{S}^{n+1-i})$?

Since the isomorphism works for any $i,n$, then we can substitute $i$ with $i-1$ to get $H_{i} (\mathbb{S}^n) \cong H_{i-1} (\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$, and so

$$H_{i} (\mathbb{S}^n) \cong H_{i-1} (\mathbb{S}^{n-1})\cong H_{i-2} (\mathbb{S}^{n-2})\cong\cdots$$

or more generally $H_{i} (\mathbb{S}^{n})\cong H_{i-k} (\mathbb{S}^{n-k})$ by induction. Now put $k=i-1$ here.

> (4) If n>1 , then how does author writes that $H_0(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}) = H_0( \mathbb{S}^n)=0$ and how does it implies that $H_1(\mathbb{S}^n)=0$

No, the author writes $H_0(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}) = H_0( \mathbb{S}^n)=\mathbb{Z}$, which follows from the other property of homology: $H_0(X)\simeq \bigoplus_{K} \mathbb{Z}$ where $K$ is the cardinality of the set of all path components. In particular if $X$ is path connected then $H_0(X)\simeq\mathbb{Z}$, which is the case for spheres of positive dimension.

Now the author writes that this gives us the following exact sequence:

$$0 \xrightarrow[]{z} H_1(\mathbb{S}^n) \xrightarrow[]{f}\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow[]{g}\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow[]{h}\mathbb{Z}\to 0$$

from the Meyer-Vietoris. To figure out why this implies that $H_1(\mathbb{S}^n)=0$ we need some algebra. This sequence implies $h$ is an epimorphism. Since every subgroup of free abelian group is free abelian, then $\ker(h)\simeq\mathbb{Z}^k$ for $k=0,1,2$. Options $k=0$ and $k=2$ cannot happen. The only left is $k=1$. And so $g$ can be thought of as an epimorphism $g:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$. But every such epimorphism is an isomorphism. And thus $g$ is injective. Meaning the only choice for $f$ is to be the zero map, i.e. its kernel is whole $H_1(\mathbb{S}^n)$. And this finally means that $0=im(z)=ker(f)=H_1(\mathbb{S}^n)$.

> (5) If n=1, then how can I get that $0 \to H_1(\mathbb{S}^{1}) \to \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$ is exact, I think I will get $0 \to H_1(\mathbb{S}^{1}) \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$ is exact and how does we get $H_1 (\mathbb{S}^0)=0$.

For $n=1$ we get similar Meyer-Vietoris sequence

$$0 \xrightarrow[]{z} H_1(\mathbb{S}^1) \xrightarrow[]{f}H_0(\mathbb{S}^0)\xrightarrow[]{g}\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow[]{h}H_0(\mathbb{S}^1)\to 0$$

except $H_0(\mathbb{S}^0)\simeq\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ because $\mathbb{S}^0$ is just two points (the only disconnected sphere), meaning two path components. That's where the additional $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ comes from.

Then we again apply algebra. Kernel of $h$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ which is image of $g$. This time kernel of $g$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ as well, and so image of $f$ is $\mathbb{Z}$. We know that $f$ is injective because of $0$ at the begining. And so $H_1(\mathbb{S}^1)$ is non-trivial and embeds into $\mathbb{Z}$. The only choice is $H_1(\mathbb{S}^1)\simeq\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you very much from bottom of my heart for writing an answer. In (2) can you please tell how $A\cap B $ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ ?

Comment: we were discussing h in (4) , I understand how k should be equal to 1, but how does using it you deduced that "And so g can be thought of as an epimorphism"? I got it how it is epimorphism. But why every such epimorphism is an isomorphism ?

Comment: In (5) How are you sure that $Ker h =\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @3ibfwcbi $A$ and $B$ are defined to be hemispheres, but actually for Meyer-Vietoris it is required for **interiors** of $A$ and $B$ to cover whole space. Literal hemispheres don't satisfy this (the union of interiors doesn't cover the common boundary, the big circle). So $A$ and $B$ have to be slightly modified: these have to be hemispheres + some $\epsilon>0$ band around them. Then interiors do cover whole sphere, but the intersection is now an $\epsilon$ band around the big circle, which deformation retracts onto the big circle, which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

Comment: @3ibfwcbi this is a general algebraic lemma. If $g:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is an epimorphism then it is an isomorphism. That's because $g$ is uniquely determined by value on its generator $g(1)$. If $g(1)\neq\pm 1$, then $g$ is not epi. But if $g(1)=\pm 1$, then $g$ is an isomorphism. Both cases can be verified manually by you.

Comment: @3ibfwcbi as for (5), so $H_0(\mathbb{S}^1)\simeq\mathbb{Z}$. And therefore $h:\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is an epimorphism (because of $0$ at the end of the sequence). So kernel, just like previously, is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^2$. It is free abelian, so it is again of the form $\mathbb{Z}^k$ for $k=0,1,2$. Since $h$ is non-trivial, then $k=2$ cannot happen. Case $k=0$ cannot happen as well, because that would imply that $h$ is injective, and thus an isomorphism. The only possibility is $k=1$.